# Cannot use HSP/HPF after installing Pipewire

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, pipewire

I'm having difficulties trying to make my new earbuds work on Ubuntu 20.04. I've followed [this tutorial](https://atish3604.medium.com/solved-bluetooth-headset-mic-not-working-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-86a5236444d0) to install pipewire, and the very first time I connected my earbuds everything seemed to work OK. But now, when I connect my earbuds and go to Settings, Audio, I get that the only possible configuration is A2DP - the first time, I had the option to choose HSP/HPF. As a consequence, I cannot use the microphone of my earbuds. I also tried to download the packages listed on the pipewire-debian repository, but still no improvements.

[Here is what I see in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJPKZ.png)

Inspecting the Bluetooth I get:

```
Device ...... (public)
    Name: Soundcore Life P2 Mini
    Alias: Soundcore Life P2 Mini
    Class: 0x00240404
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
```

While pactl info returns:

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 33
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 91
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: ...
Host Name: ...
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.40)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
```

Journalct:

```
dec 12 17:45:22 boris-Swift-SF314-52 systemd[987]: pipewire-pulse.service: Succeeded.
dec 12 17:45:23 boris-Swift-SF314-52 systemd[987]: pipewire-media-session.service: Succeeded.
dec 12 17:45:23 boris-Swift-SF314-52 systemd[987]: pipewire.service: Succeeded.
dec 12 17:45:23 boris-Swift-SF314-52 systemd[987]: pipewire-pulse.socket: Succeeded.
dec 12 17:45:23 boris-Swift-SF314-52 systemd[987]: pipewire.socket: Succeeded.
dec 12 17:46:07 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5: Failed to register battery provider. Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod
dec 12 17:46:07 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5: BlueZ Battery Provider is not available, won't retry to register it. Make sure you are running BlueZ 5.56+ with experimental features to use Battery Provider.
dec 12 17:47:23 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b6811fc08: error 24
dec 12 17:47:23 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b6811fc08: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:47:23 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b6811fc08: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:47:23 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b6811fc08: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:47:23 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b6811fc08: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:47:23 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5: Failed to release transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_5C_56_A4_32_B4_67/sep1/fd0: Method "Release" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.MediaTransport1" doesn't exist
dec 12 17:47:23 boris-Swift-SF314-52 dbus-daemon[797]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.87" (uid=1000 pid=1598 comm="/usr/bin/pipewire-media-session " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.3" (uid=0 pid=794 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
dec 12 17:47:56 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680ffce8: error 24
dec 12 17:47:56 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680ffce8: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:47:56 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680ffce8: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:47:56 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5: Failed to release transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_5C_56_A4_32_B4_67/fd1: Method "Release" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.MediaTransport1" doesn't exist
dec 12 17:47:56 boris-Swift-SF314-52 dbus-daemon[797]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.87" (uid=1000 pid=1598 comm="/usr/bin/pipewire-media-session " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.3" (uid=0 pid=794 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
dec 12 17:48:21 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5: Transport Acquire() failed for transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_5C_56_A4_32_B4_67/fd2 (Input/output error)
dec 12 17:48:21 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.audioadapter: 0x560b68157508: can't send command 2: Input/output error
dec 12 17:48:21 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: pw.node: (bluez_output.5C_56_A4_32_B4_67.a2dp-sink-19) suspended -> error (Start error: Input/output error)
dec 12 17:48:21 boris-Swift-SF314-52 dbus-daemon[797]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.87" (uid=1000 pid=1598 comm="/usr/bin/pipewire-media-session " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.3" (uid=0 pid=794 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
dec 12 17:49:02 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680642f8: error 24
dec 12 17:49:02 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680642f8: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:49:02 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680642f8: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:49:02 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680642f8: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:49:02 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680642f8: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:49:02 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680642f8: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:49:02 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5: Failed to release transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_5C_56_A4_32_B4_67/sep1/fd3: Method "Release" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.MediaTransport1" doesn't exist
dec 12 17:49:02 boris-Swift-SF314-52 dbus-daemon[797]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.87" (uid=1000 pid=1598 comm="/usr/bin/pipewire-media-session " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.3" (uid=0 pid=794 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
dec 12 17:49:35 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b68064348: error 24
dec 12 17:49:35 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b68064348: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:49:35 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b68064348: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:49:35 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5: Failed to release transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_5C_56_A4_32_B4_67/fd4: Method "Release" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.MediaTransport1" doesn't exist
dec 12 17:49:35 boris-Swift-SF314-52 dbus-daemon[797]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.87" (uid=1000 pid=1598 comm="/usr/bin/pipewire-media-session " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.3" (uid=0 pid=794 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
dec 12 17:51:09 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680643e8: error 24
dec 12 17:51:09 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680643e8: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:51:09 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680643e8: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:51:09 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5: Failed to release transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_5C_56_A4_32_B4_67/fd5: Method "Release" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.MediaTransport1" doesn't exist
dec 12 17:51:09 boris-Swift-SF314-52 dbus-daemon[797]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.87" (uid=1000 pid=1598 comm="/usr/bin/pipewire-media-session " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.3" (uid=0 pid=794 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
dec 12 17:51:29 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680643e8: error 24
dec 12 17:51:29 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x560b680643e8: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 17:51:29 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[1598]: spa.bluez5: Failed to release transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_5C_56_A4_32_B4_67/fd6: Method "Release" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.MediaTransport1" doesn't exist
dec 12 17:51:29 boris-Swift-SF314-52 dbus-daemon[797]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.87" (uid=1000 pid=1598 comm="/usr/bin/pipewire-media-session " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.3" (uid=0 pid=794 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
dec 12 17:52:44 boris-Swift-SF314-52 systemd[1591]: pipewire-pulse.service: Succeeded.
dec 12 17:52:44 boris-Swift-SF314-52 systemd[1591]: pipewire-media-session.service: Succeeded.
dec 12 17:52:44 boris-Swift-SF314-52 systemd[1591]: pipewire.service: Succeeded.
dec 12 17:52:44 boris-Swift-SF314-52 systemd[1591]: pipewire-pulse.socket: Succeeded.
dec 12 17:52:44 boris-Swift-SF314-52 systemd[1591]: pipewire.socket: Succeeded.
dec 12 17:53:13 boris-Swift-SF314-52 dbus-daemon[798]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' unit='rtkit-daemon.service' requested by ':1.30' (uid=125 pid=1065 comm="/usr/bin/pipewire-media-session " label="unconfined")
dec 12 17:53:51 boris-Swift-SF314-52 systemd[984]: pipewire-pulse.service: Succeeded.
dec 12 17:53:51 boris-Swift-SF314-52 systemd[984]: pipewire-media-session.service: Succeeded.
....
dec 12 18:22:58 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[4657]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x559ff4240048: error 24
dec 12 18:22:58 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[4657]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x559ff4240048: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 18:22:58 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[4657]: spa.bluez5.sink.a2dp: 0x559ff4240048: ioctl fail: Bad file descriptor
dec 12 18:22:58 boris-Swift-SF314-52 pipewire-media-session[4657]: spa.bluez5: Failed to release transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_5C_56_A4_32_B4_67/fd13: Method "Release" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.MediaTransport1" doesn't exist
dec 12 18:22:58 boris-Swift-SF314-52 dbus-daemon[798]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.151" (uid=1000 pid=4657 comm="/usr/bin/pipewire-media-session " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.3" (uid=0 pid=792 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
```

Do you know what could have gone wrong?
Thanks for your help!